# Error using aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am using an attribute of type SObject[]

> aura:attribute name="testDetails" type="SObject[]" access="global"

**This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application.
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 939675373-29354 (1831094297)**

Comment: Can you please post your component code and js controller if required.

Comment: The problem doesn't come from the code you posted.

Comment: Turn on and look at the server-side debug logs.

Comment: Tried all these things but could not figure it out, tried to create the component dynamically usinc `$A.createComponent`, and avoided the use of aura:iteration. It worked.